# Python: how parse columns names from SQL fragments in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the data frame contains an **ID** and **CONDITION** which is an SQL fragment

```
|ID|CONDITION                                                               |
|--|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1 |STATUS = "ABCD"                                                         |
|1 |STATUS = "DEFG"                                                         |
|1 |CASE WHEN STATUS = "XYZ" AND MOD = 1 THEN "CORRECT" ELSE "INCORRECT" END|
|2 |CODEX = 100                                                             |
```

Requirement is to parse out column names from SQL **CONDITION** and create unique combinations of **ID** and columns

```
Am expecting 
|ID|COLUMN |
|--|-------|
|1 |STATUS |
|1 |MOD    |
|2 |CODEX  |
```

EDIT: In the condition column we write text which will be equivalent to SQL and it appends to a sql as column.
The output is three rows because the first row and second row for ID = 1 only one condition (column) STATUS is used. SO for ID = 1 the columns list will be STATUS and MOD. for ID=2 it is CODEX.

Comment: What is "kind of database columns"?

Comment: Please describe the logic that determines which words are selected, and why there are only three rows in your desired output when the input has four.

Comment: Sorry Updated the question with more explanation.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68880439/edit) the question and explain how do you know which word to extract. For example, on first row, you are extracting first word `STATUS`, and in the third row, you are extracting `MOD`. If you don't explain the question well, we can not answer it and this question can not be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this is really a parsing question.  You have parts of SQL statements where you want to parse out column names
- this project https://github.com/zbrookle/sql_to_ibis has a full SQL grammar defined for https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
- now just need to integrate this

  1. establish a LALR parser using grammar from GitHub project
  2. for each row call parser and extract column names from parsed SQL segment **output 1**
  3. now look at distinct columns by *ID* **output 2**

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lark import Lark, UnexpectedToken
import requests

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""|ID|CONDITION                                                               |
|1 |STATUS = "ABCD"                                                         |
|1 |STATUS = "DEFG"                                                         |
|1 |CASE WHEN STATUS = "XYZ" AND MOD = 1 THEN "CORRECT" ELSE "INCORRECT" END|
|2 |CODEX = 100                                                             |"""), sep="|")
df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if "Unnamed" in c]).pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c:c.strip() for c in d.columns}))

grammar = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zbrookle/sql_to_ibis/main/sql_to_ibis/grammar/sql.lark").text
cname = []
def columntokencallback(t):
    global cname
    cname.append(t.value)
    return t
parser = Lark(grammar, start="where_expr", parser="lalr", lexer_callbacks={"CNAME":columntokencallback})


def columns(s):
    global cname
    cname = []
    try:
        parser.parse(s)
    except UnexpectedToken as e:
        pass

    return cname


df["columns"] = df["CONDITION"].apply(columns)

df
```

### output 1

|  | ID | CONDITION | columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | STATUS = "ABCD" | ['STATUS'] |
| 1 | 1 | STATUS = "DEFG" | ['STATUS'] |
| 2 | 1 | CASE WHEN STATUS = "XYZ" AND MOD = 1 THEN "CORRECT" ELSE "INCORRECT" END | ['STATUS', 'MOD'] |
| 3 | 2 | CODEX = 100 | ['CODEX'] |

```
df.explode("columns").loc[:,["ID","columns"]].drop_duplicates()
```

### output 2

|  | ID | columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | STATUS |
| 2 | 1 | MOD |
| 3 | 2 | CODEX |

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2],
        "CONDITION": [
            'STATUS = "ABCD"',
            'STATUS = "DEFG"',
            'CASE WHEN STATUS = "XYZ" AND MOD = 1 THEN "CORRECT" ELSE "INCORRECT" END',
            "CODEX = 100",
        ],
    }
)
KEYWORDS = ("STATUS", "MOD", "CODEX")  # Add more keywords as needed
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [], "COLUMN": []})

# Iterate to find matching rows
for keyword in KEYWORDS:
    temp_df = df.loc[df["CONDITION"].str.contains(keyword), ["ID"]]
    temp_df["COLUMN"] = keyword
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp_df])

# Clean-up
new_df["ID"] = new_df["ID"].astype(int)
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
# Outputs
   ID  COLUMN
0   1  STATUS
1   1     MOD
2   2   CODEX
```

Comment: this is searching for a static list of columns, not parsing out columns from SQL fragments

Comment: @ RobRaymond True. I answered the question as it was posted.