# How to convert Python list into pandas DataFrame or excel file output with specific requirements as below:

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have list derived from JSON as below :

```
list = ['select', 'name1 = a.column1', 'name2 = a.column2', 'name3 = a.[column3]',
        'from', 'xyz.[Table1$Name] c',
        'select', 'name2 = b.othercolumn1', 'name2 = b.[othercolumn2]', 'name3 = b.othercolumn3',
        'from', 'abc.[Table2$Name] d',
        'where', 'x.[TableX] = '123',++++ and so on.....]
```

The output I want is a data frame with 2 columns which I can extract as excel as below:

```
Table Name         Column Name
Table1$Name        column1
Table1$Name        column2
Table1$Name        column3
Table2$Name        othercolumn1
Table2$Name        othercolumn2
Table2$Name        othercolumn3
```

I have tried in many ways but I am unable to achieve the desired output, I only want to have excel file output for all columns from this ".bim" file against the respective tables, everything else like where statement, [], c, a., b., should be removed in  final output.

Comment: this looks like an sql parsing question.  have answered similar before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880439/python-how-parse-columns-names-from-sql-fragments-in-a-dataframe-column/68884298#68884298

Comment: Your *list* seems to contain a number of splitted SQL SELECT statements. You have shows two (incorrects) trivial single table select. Do you only have trivial select like that, or could your list contain other sql statements or multi-table selects?

Comment: @SergeBallesta my list contains numerous "select" statements followed by "from" statements. 
e.g. ["select", "column1", "from", "table1", "where", "abc=xyz", "select", "abc1", "abc2", "abc3", "from", "table2", ++++ .. . .. . ].
The output I want is only table names and column names as DataFrame.

Comment: @RobRaymond I have gone through your answer on the specified thread, however, in my case it is different and cannot be solved with the same approach. It would be really great if you could assist me because I have been spending time since last week to find a solution. Thank you.. :)

Comment: There are 2 possible ways here. One is to *join* the elements of the list to build true select statements and use a SQL parser on them. The other is to try to directly use the elements themselves using `'select'`, `'from'` and `'where'` as delimiting tokens. The way to go depends on what your list actually contains: first way should be more complex but probably more robust if the SQL statements are correct, second way should be simpler but is only an option if the list is limited to trivial select statements. As you have only shown garbage, I cannot say more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- as per comments, you are really asking how to parse SQL into it's components
- this approach uses **lark** to parse.  This is a sophisticated topic, so have demonstrated how to integrate with **pandas** in another way
- your sample SQL is not valid based on grammar I have used.  IMHO this is a decent grammar for SQL.  I have worked with many database engines,  not one that I have worked with allows assignment in select clause or used of **$** in column or table names

```
from lark import Lark, Tree, Visitor, Tree, Token, UnexpectedInput
import requests
import pandas as pd

grammar = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zbrookle/sql_to_ibis/main/sql_to_ibis/grammar/sql.lark"
).text
parser = Lark(grammar, start="query_expr")


class sqlparts(Visitor):
    __columns = []
    __tables = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.__columns = []
        self.__tables = []

    def column_name(self, tree):
        self.__columns += [
            tok.value
            for tok in tree.scan_values(
                lambda v: isinstance(v, Token) and v.type == "CNAME"
            )
        ]

    def table(self, tree):
        self.__tables += [
            tok.value
            for tok in tree.scan_values(
                lambda v: isinstance(v, Token) and v.type == "CNAME"
            )
        ]

    def data(self):
        return {"columns": self.__columns, "tables": self.__tables}


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "sql": [
            "select col1, col2, col3 from table1, table2 where col7=8",
            'select "hello" from a_long_table where col7=8',
            'select "hello" from a_long_table where col7=8 groupby col8',
            "select col$ from tables",
        ]
    }
)


def applyparse(sql):
    d = sqlparts()
    try:
        t = parser.parse(sql, start="query_expr")
        d.visit(t)
        return d.data()
    except UnexpectedInput as e:
        return {"error": e}


df.join(df["sql"].apply(applyparse).apply(pd.Series))
```

| sql | columns | tables | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| select col1, col2, col3 from table1, table2 where col7=8 | ['col7', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'] | ['table1', 'table2'] | nan |
| select "hello" from a_long_table where col7=8 | ['col7'] | ['a_long_table'] | nan |
| select "hello" from a_long_table where col7=8 groupby col8 | ['col7', 'col8'] | ['a_long_table'] | nan |
| select col$ from tables | nan | nan | No terminal matches '$' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 11 |